# Doing something wrong when trying to make a dropdown mene in CSS

Tags: html, css, dropdown, display

I've been trying to figure out what is why the dropdown menu isnt changing from display: none; into display: block; when i hover over it.

I briefly looked at a dropdown menu CSS tutorial just to get a basic understanding on how it works but after watching it a few times i have no clue what is not working

P.S i am relatively new to this stuff

Code:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        .navbar ul li{
            display: inline-flex;
            margin-left: 8rem;
            list-style: none;
            color: white;
            padding: .5rem;
            border-radius: 1rem;
        }
        .navbar{
            background: rgb(0, 120, 0);
            padding: 1.25rem;
            font-size: larger;
            text-decoration: none;
          
        }
        .navbar:link{
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        .navbar ul li:hover{
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        }
        .drop-1{
            display: none;
            background-color: darkgreen;
            position: absolute;
            left: 6rem;
            
            
        }
        .drop-1 a{
            color: lightgreen;
        }
        .drop-1 ul li{
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            padding-bottom: .5rem;
            padding-top: .5rem;
            padding-left: 1rem;
            padding-right: 1rem;
            display: block;
            
        }
        .drop-1 ul li:last-child{
            border: none;
        }
        .drop-1 ul li:first-child{
            border-top: 1px solid black;
        }
        .navbar ul li:hover .drop-1{
            display: block;
        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">dropdown1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dropdown2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dropdown3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dropdown4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dropdown5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown must be in the structure of your styles. You have this style:

```
.navbar ul li:hover .drop-1{
   display: block;
}
```

Which means that you have a class navbar, and then ul with some li and, "inside" an element with a drop-1 class. When you are hover that li, then your drop-1 element will be visible.

If you put a dropdown inside some li of your navbar, you can see the dropdown.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Test1</a>
          <div class="drop-1">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">dropdown1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">dropdown2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">dropdown3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">dropdown4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">dropdown5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You need one dropdown for each menú in your navbar.

**UPDATE**

Well, maybe a bit difficult at first but the concept is always the same. Check this:

```
a span {
   // Any span inside a link will be hidden by default
   display: none;
}

a:hover span {
   // but when you are hover the link, the span will be visible
   display: block;
}

<a>Always visible <span>Visible only on hover</span></a>
```

The CSS it's applied to the span but the "hover" of the link it's who change the display of the span.

Comment: This works now, but I am confused on how it works. you took the test1 out of the list and there isnt any css that makes the drop-1 appear when you hover over an anchor element.

Comment: @AtomicPikle `Test1` is still inside the list,s/he wrap the dropdown inside the first `li` element

Comment: The test1 link doing nothing. Only show a text for the menu. The CSS ".navbar ul li:hover .drop-1" don't use the link. The rule say that when you are hover the li, the drop-1 will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Here your code fixed. Besides Victor clarification there are a few more things you could solve about the code. I paste it here if you want to copy it.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.navbar ul li {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 8rem;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    padding: .5rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

.navbar {
    background: rgb(0, 120, 0);
    padding: 1.25rem;
    font-size: larger;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.navbar:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navbar ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.drop-1 {
    display: none;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    z-index: 1;
}

.drop-1 a {
    color: lightgreen;
}

.drop-1 ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    display: block;
}

.drop-1 ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}

.drop-1 ul li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .drop-1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test1</a>
                <div class="drop-1">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">dropdown1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">dropdown2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">dropdown3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">dropdown4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">dropdown5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```